# How to send a list as a parameter to Firebase Functions in Flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-functions

I would like to know, how to send or post a list (of maps) using the [Cloud Functions Plugin for Flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_functions).

I have some maps like these:

```
var customer1 = {'name':'tom','lastname':'smith'}; 
var customer2 = {'name':'bob','lastname':'lee'}; 
var customer3 = {'name':'george','lastname':'collins'};
```

These maps later become a list:

`var _customerList = [customer1, customer2, customer3];`

I am trying to send or post this list as a parameter to Cloud Functions for Flutter like this:

```
   var _data = {
      'customerList': _customerList,
    };

    final HttpsCallable callable = CloudFunctions.instance
        .getHttpsCallable(functionName: 'createCustomer')
      ..timeout = const Duration(seconds: 30);

    final HttpsCallableResult result = await callable.call(_data);
```

However, I am getting this error:

`I/flutter (11486): Invalid argument: Instance of ...`

If I try to post a simple string everything works fine.  Nevertheless, it seems that I am not posting the list of maps correctly.

I am using this version of the plugin:

```
dependencies:
  cloud_functions: ^0.3.0+1
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What format should be?

Comment: You can also use another tool. It generates code without dependencies. The same source code that you would write with your hands. Or at least very close to such a code. https://github.com/mezoni/yaml2podo

Comment: Have you tried adding 'data:' on your post so in your case:  var _data = {
      'data': _customerList,
    };